# Achieve (possibly) covariant cast

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting, covariance

### I have the following classes:

```
X : BaseX
```

---

```
XView : BaseView<X>
```

---

```
XDAO : BaseDAO<X>
```

---

```
MainViewModel<TX, TView, TDAO>
where TX : X
where TView : View<X>
where TDAO : DAO<X>
```

---

```
XMainViewModel : MainViewModel<X, XView, XDAO>
```

---

I have an instance of `XMainViewModel<X, XView, XDAO>`. I want to cast this to `MainViewModel<BaseX, BaseView<X>, BaseDAO<X>>`. Is this possible? It might have covariants involved. I'm not familiar with covariants, and only started using generics not long ago so I'm rather confused here (I also hope I did not make any typos in the question). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Variance is only supported by interfaces, not classes.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this possible?

No. Generic covariance and contravariance are supported only on interfaces and delegates constructed with reference types.

> I'm rather confused here

It's a confusing topic. One way to think about it is to always be asking yourself "suppose this were legal; what could go wrong?" You say

> I have `XMainViewModel<X, XView, XDAO>`. I want to cast this to `MainViewModel<BaseX, BaseView<X>, BaseDAO<X>>`

Let's look at a simpler example. You have a `List<Giraffe>` and you wish to cast it to `List<Animal>`.  What can go wrong?

```
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();
giraffes.Add(new Giraffe());
List<Animal> animals = (List<Animal>)giraffes; // This is illegal. What if it were legal?
animals.Add(new Tiger());
Giraffe g = giraffes[1]; // And we just put a Tiger into a variable of type Giraffe.
```

That's why this is illegal, and why your example would also be illegal.  But this is legal:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = giraffes;
```

Why is that legal?  Because **IEnumerable provides no way at all for a tiger to be inserted**. The interface has been marked as safe for covariance, and the C# compiler has verified that it is safe, so this conversion is allowed.

I've written lots of SO answers and blog posts and articles on covariance and contravariance, so do some searches if you want to learn more about this feature and why we designed it as we did.

You could make your example legal by (1) make `MainViewModel<A, B, C>` into an interface and mark it `IMainViewModel<out A, out B, out C>`, and then (2) ensure that no method of the interface takes an A, B or C as a parameter, no property of type A, B or C has a setter, and so on. That is, every usage of A, B and C is an *output* position, not an *input* position. That's how the compiler knows that it is safe for covariance.

> I also hope I did not make any typos in the question

It's "covariance", not "covariants". "Covariance" is a noun; "covariant" is an adjective.

Comment: One again, with your "break it down" answer, I understand something I did not an hour ago.